# Hexadecimal Parameter "or" | Operator in C

Tags: c, constants

I'm pretty new to C, I come from a web development background so I'm a little bit unsure of some of the bits and bytes coding that I have seen C programmers use. I'm looking at some C code that passes in a parameter to a function.

```
insert_chem(int jobId, ...);
```

And when this function is called, the jobId passed is actually a constant, that is originally defined like this:

```
CYCLE_JOB_MEM = 0x00020000
```

it would be used like this:

```
insert_chem(CYCLE_JOB_MEM, ...);
```

I have seen that this can be passed along in with the same first parameter:

```
#define DETAILS 0x80000000
```

Like this:

```
insert_chem(CYCLE_JOB_MEM|DETAILS, ...);
```

What exactly is happening here? This code is pretty old, does C still use practices like these? If someone could provide me with some keywords and a simple explanation, then I could continue to research about this.

Sorry if this stuff is simple!

UPDATE:

These appear to be hexidecimal values, how are multiple values passed in? Are they split apart when the function is entered? Why not pass multiple parameters in the first place?

Comment: If you're curious I've been reading this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html

The C part of course not the C++ part

Comment: Sorry so @HunterMcMillen these are Hexidecimal values, how is CYCLE_JOB_MEM|DETAILS passed into the function as one parameter?

Comment: @SSHThis They are integers, just is a different base (base 16).

Comment: Google *bitflags*, quite more specific than "hexadecimal".

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic way to use one parameter for multiple things, often called "bitmask" or "bitflags". The key here is to understand how numbers are represented in the computer, and the operator "or" (`|`).

If you understand how numbers are stored in the computer, and how the or operator works, then the rest is pretty straight forward.

Why not multple parameters? Well, if it's only two, then perhaps it's not a big issue, but imagine that if you have 16 different options?

Comment: Perhaps use a word not mentioned once in this answer: **bitflags** (though I would have accepted *bitmask* as well).

Comment: Thx for answering the last part about the multiple operators, it's a good point

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice easy one...  The | in "CYCLE_JOB_MEM|DETAILS" is performing a binary OR operation on the two values.  The result of OR-ing 0x10 with 0x02 would be 0x12.

In your case, it's OR-ing 0x00020000 with 0x80000000 resulting in the value of 0x80020000 being passed in as the argument.

EDIT:  This sort of thing is commonly done with communications packets.  Where each Bit is used to indicate a different condition or a fault (for example).  This way, you can indicate 8 boolean (true/false) conditions with a single byte.

```
#define PACKET_ACK 0x80
#define PACKET_NAK 0x40
#define PACKET_ERR 0x20
#define PACKET_WTF 0x10
#define PACKET_LOL 0x01
```

etc...

If you pass in (PACKET_ACK|PACKET_WTF) the incoming argument will have a value of 0x81.

This is then often handled by (as per comment)

```
if ( arg & PACKET_ACK ){/*do some stuff*/}
if ( arg & PACKET_WTF ){/*do some other stuff*/}
```

Comment: ... which can then be split back using the `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The single `|` is the *bitwise-or operator*.  A Boolean OR operation is performed for each bit in the two operands.  For example, the bitwise-or operation of 2 and 4 is

```
  0010
| 0100
------
  0110
```

giving the value 6.  The result of `CYCLE_JOB_MEM|DETAILS` is 0x80020000; that's the value that gets passed as the first argument to `insert_chem`.

For more information, google "C bitwise operators".